# Sum of branded and non-branded clicks is much lower than the total reported by Google Search Console

Tags: google-search-console, search-analytics

I even filtered brand and non-brand keywords to see clicks. Suddenly i realized, that the whole amount of clicks shown by GSC is much higher, than the sum of brand and non-brand clicks.

Why is it so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/7576553?hl=en

> Discrepancies between chart totals and table totals You can see
> differences between the chart totals and the table totals for several
> reasons:
> ... When filtering by page or query, the "matches" and "does
> not match" totals might not add up to the unfiltered total. For
> example, adding the totals for "Queries containing:mouse" and "Queries
> not containing:mouse" might not equal the total values when no query
> filters are applied. This is because anonymized queries are omitted,
> and data is truncated due to serving limitations."

I have the same problem. GSC reported 6,500 total klicks, 2,500 with brand-keyword, 500 without.  So I am missing data for more than half my traffic. Seems like we can do nothing about that.

Also you can look at this thread here where they discuss the same problem:
https://support.google.com/webmasters/thread/4924855?hl=en

Comment: `anonymized queries are omitted, and data is truncated due to serving limitations...` very funny math. Is it still math